# Retrieve json value into columns when values are not named

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a column named Username (varchar max, allows nulls) in a table.  The table may have multiple entries that are all stored in this column.  It is currently displayed in this format:

["name1","name2"]

I am trying to pull out name1 and name2 into separate rows.  I cannot figure out how to do so.  Here is the query that I currently have that is closest:

```
select u.id, a.[Username]
from dbo.Users u
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Username) WITH ([Username] varchar(max)) a
```

This is pulling them out in rows correctly but the rows display NULL instead of the value.  I checked that the name matches the column name in syntax and it does.

Comment: Remove the `WITH` clause.

Comment: You can name JSON value nested in array by passing a `$` path in the `WITH` clause - `SELECT a.Username
FROM OPENJSON('["John","Kat"]') WITH ([Username] varchar(max) '$') a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPENJSON function is looking for a column named 'Username'.  Instead, try giving OPENJSON 'oj' an alias and opening the JSON without specifying a schema.  Then add oj.value to the SELECT list.  Something like this

```
select u.id, oj.[value] as Username
from dbo.Users u
     cross apply openjson(u.Username) oj;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the unexpected results is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#with_clause):  *"...OPENJSON matches keys in jsonExpression with the column names in with_clause (in this case, matches keys implies that it is case sensitive). If a column name does not match a key name, you can provide an optional column_path..."*. Your input JSON is an array of scalar values and there isn't a key `"username"`.

But, you **can** use `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause). Just use the correct path (`'$'` in your case).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (id int, username varchar(max))
INSERT INTO Users (id, username) VALUES (1, '["name1","name2"]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT u.id, a.[username]
FROM Users u
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (u.[username]) WITH ([username] varchar(max) '$') a
```

Result:

```
id  username
1   name1
1   name2
```